# To Share on samba a External USB Hard Drive on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, mount

I have been looking for one month now and cant find any answers to sharing a external hard drive usb with samba using Ubuntu 14.04, I have read a lot of forums and accessed advice. I always get the same error messages occurring, tried all different formats on the hard drive.

I can share desktop folders without a problem but not on an external hard drives no luck.

This is the error message I am getting

"Unable to access location Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied"

Thanks